# Fast way to push and shift arrays in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6

I have a data stream which continuously needs to update an array. The array itself is always bigger than the stream which is coming in. This would mean that I have to concat the buffer to the array and shift everything. However, concatenation is slow so I was wondering if there is a fast way of doing this?

Example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var stream = [7,8,9];
array = magicalFunction(array,stream); // outputs [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The array function is used for plotting with ChartJS. It's a rolling plot so as data comes in (it comes in chunks) I have to update the chart by shifting the entire data set.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), not an array. Just don't do any shifting.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on how you will use `array`? That may open doors to suggesting other, more efficient solutions.

Comment: @trincot I have added extra description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). But if that is faster than concat ...?

```js
var magicalFunction = (a, s) => [...a.slice(s.length - a.length), ...s],
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    stream = [7, 8, 9];

array = magicalFunction(array,stream);

console.log(array);
```

With [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
var magicalFunction = (a, s) => a.slice(s.length - a.length).concat(s);
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    stream = [7, 8, 9];

array = magicalFunction(array,stream);

console.log(array);
```

With [`Array.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```js
var magicalFunction = (a, s) => (s.unshift(...a.slice(s.length - a.length)), s);
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    stream = [7, 8, 9];

array = magicalFunction(array,stream);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's going to be even slower

Comment: @dfsq, right, but some information is missing, like how long is the buffer, what should happen, if `stream` is greater then the buffer?

Comment: As I've said, stream is always smaller than the array. Buffer can range from 100 elements to 1000 elements

Comment: Or maybe it's actually not that slow. I run some pref tests and looks like spread (first version) runs way faster than concat + slice or even simple for loop + push/unshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a .push:

```
array.push.apply(array, stream);
```

or in ES2015 you can use the triple dots:

```
array.push(...stream)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this simply concat the stream to array?

Answer (score 0):

How about a Spread

```
var stream = [7,8,9];
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6, ...stream];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late to answer but you could do this with ES6 like this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let stream = [7, 8, 9, 1];

const mergedArray = [...array, ...stream]

// fetch only distinct values
const distinctMergedArray = Array.from(new Set(mergedArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let stream = [7, 8, 9, 1];
//set to get distinct value and spread operator to merge two arrays 
const resultArray = new Set([...array, ...stream])
```